# Perl "keys on reference is experimental" warning

Tags: perl, dictionary, hash

My perl program is throwing some warnings, and I am yet to have any luck searching the Internet for a solution. Is there any way I can rewrite the following code snippet so that no warnings are thrown?

"keys on reference is experimental at...":

```
foreach my $key ( keys %$api_decoded_result{'query'}->{'pages'} ) {
    @words = split / /, $api_decoded_result->{'query'}->{'pages'}{$key}->{'extract'};
}
```

Comment: Even with the oldest version of Perl I have handy, 5.14, that actually produces `syntax error at a.pl line 1, near "$api_decoded_result{"`, because `%$api_decoded_result{'query'}` makes no sense.

Comment: I think it's experimental on 5.20.2 but removed in the more recent versions, hence the syntax error

Comment: No, the error you get from `keys($ref)` in 5.24+ is `Experimental keys on scalar is now forbidden`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup. This is because of precedence of operator dereferencing. `%$api_decoded_result` binds tighter than the `{'query'}`.

```
keys %{$api_decoded_result{'query'}->{'pages'}}
```

Will do what you want.

Comment: you forgot a `->` between `$api_decoded_result` and `{'query'}` I think

Comment: Possibly. Without knowing what the source data structure the OP is using, I chose to copy it.

Comment: Actually he was treating it like a hashref and not a hash : `%$api_decoded_result` seems to aim at accessing the reference, and he uses `$api_decoded_result->{'query'}` inside the loop... Since he accepted your answer I guess it's ok, but it's quite weird though.